# Python: Alternative to Panda's merge()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join, merge

I'm currently working on several dataframes which some of them has over 3 million rows, but for simplicity of this question let's assume I have this df:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'a' : np.random.randint(1, 100, 100),
                   'b' : np.random.randint(1, 300, 100),
                   'c' : np.random.randint(1, 500, 100),
                   'id': np.random.randint(1, 11,  100),})
```

And df2:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'id': np.arange(1, 11),
                    'd' : np.random.randint(1, 100, 10),
                    'e' : np.random.randint(1, 200, 10),
                    'f' : np.random.randint(1, 300, 10),
                    'g' : np.random.randint(1, 400, 10),
                    'h' : np.random.randint(1, 500, 10)})
```

What I want is to combine df & df2 by the common column 'id'. The issue is that while I'm using Google Colab, the session keeps crashing upon merging dataframes from RAM overusage. This usually does not happen but the overusage of RAM was probably due to size of data I'm working on

Thus I'm looking for better alternatives; so far I've tried these codes:

```
 df = pd.merge(df, df2, on= 'id', how= 'outer')

 df = df.set_index('id')
 df2 = df2.set_index('id')
 df = df.join(df2, how='outer')
 df = df.reset_index()
 # Session crashes upon resetting index

 for c in df2.columns[1:]:
    df[c] = df['id'].map(df2.set_index('id')[c])
 # Works, but takes considerably long
```

Please advise

Comment: load the dataframe in chunks. say 1 million rows or less.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively You can do:

Firstly make **'id'** columns of both df's as their index:

```
df=df.set_index('id')
df2=df2.set_index('id')
```

Finally use `isin()` method to create a boolean mask that check if index of df is in the index of df2 and pass that mask to df and using `assign()` method assign values:

```
df=df[df.index.isin(df2.index)].assign(d=df2['d'],e=df2['e'],f=df2['f'],g=df2['g'],h=df2['h'])
```

If needed use `reset_index()` method:

```
df=df.reset_index()
```